# Using HTML elements inside an XML loaded by Flash

Tags: html, xml, actionscript-3, text, coding-style

I am trying to use html elements to style text inside an XML file that is loaded and displayed by flash.  When I do this the text will not display at all. Here is a chunck of my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Page>
    <Title>You should be <b>Bold</b> ! </Title>
<Page>
```

When I try the code below, it displays but ignores the b tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Page>
    <Title>You should be &lt;b&gt;Bold&lt;/b&gt; ! </Title>
<Page>
```

Here is the actionscript that sets the dynamic text field:

```
Container.Title.htmlText = xmlData.Title[0];
```

From what I can tell, this should be entirely doable. Tutorials and reference online gives no hist to the problem. Seems simple but its driving me nuts.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I still have no resolution for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the HTML in CDATA tags, like so:

```
<![CDATA[ -- your html content here -- ]]>
```

Comment: This didn't work. with the CDATA tags, the text was displayed but the tags ignored when I used <b> (previously didn't display at all), when I did &lt;b&gt; it displayed as <b>. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just HTML encoding the HTML and then seeing if the actionscript handles it appropriately? You might have to decode it in actionscript, not sure.

Comment: I have encoded it in my 2nd code block.  It ignores the tags and shows the text without styling.  It's as if there is no default css for b or strong or em.